# ManyToManyField value is None

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

Im trying to use ManytoManyField for my Book , but it is showing None in web page and administration.Here is my code

```py
class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    publish_year = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    language = LanguageField(max_length=40, default=False)
    age_group = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GROUP_CHOICES)
    downloaded_times = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    rate_times = models.IntegerField()
    rate_total = models.FloatField()
    book_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='book_cover_image', default="image.png")
    pdf_file = models.FileField(default=True, upload_to='media')


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}|-|{self.category}|-|{self.author}"
```

In views.py I have

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = Book.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) 
    )
    print(Book.category)
    return object_list
```

The Category looks like this:
[image: The Category looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

`book.category` is a *manager*, not a `QuerySet`, you can work with [**`.all()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all) to convert this to a `QuerySet`, so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = Book.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) 
    )
    for obj in object_list:
        print(obj.category.all())
    return object_list
```

In the `__str__` you thus work with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}|-|{self.category.all()}|-|{self.author}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in admin page its shown like this 
 Emma|-|<QuerySet [<Category: Drama>]>|-|Jane Austen

Comment: in web page its still None

Comment: @user15441078: in the web page, you render it with `.all` as well, so `{% for cat in object.category.all %}{{ cat }}{% endfor %}` for example, with `object`, the object for wich you want to render this.

Comment: I add {{ book.category.all|join:', ' }} and  now it works, thank you very much.